# Use camera in react native app with background audio playing? (Like a song from music app)

Tags: swift, xcode, react-native, react-native-camera, ios-camera

When recording a video or opening the camera with react native background audio is paused.

Is there a specific or recommended way to allow background audio to play when the camera is open?

I am using react-native-camera and have used react-native-image-picker previously but they do not have anything in their documentation related.

After doing some looking around, in swift there is AVAudioSession which could potentially be used on the native side?

I would love some recommendations and guidance to resolve this!

Comment: any solution for this so far?